# SSIS 2012 truncates result set of Execute SQL task

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, etl

Searched high and low on this and found many suggestions, but nothing that works for me.  We have a table with a field that stores SQL queries in a text type column, and the query is subsequently called by other objects, thus a need to escape certain characters.

I built a piece of SQL code to do that which works great.  The problem is, when put in an Execute SQL task and assigning the results to a String variable, the text is truncated at seemingly random, ex. the most recent attempt truncated 4184 characters to 4058.

I know that nvarchar is limited to 4000 characters in SSIS.  One suggestion was to use nvarchar(max) source data type and Object variable type.  That fails with this error:

"An error occurred while extracting the result into a variable of type (DBTYPE_WSTR)".

Another was to use ntext in the source query.  That fails with this error:

"The text, ntext, and image data types are invalid for local variables."

Am I missing something?  What's the correct way to put a long string into an Execute SQL result set variable?

Here's the original code to get the SQL command, the code that works but truncates.  The puts an escaped single quote around the ID.  (These particular IDs are varchar because they can contain letters.)

```
DECLARE @IDList VARCHAR(8000)
SELECT @IDList = COALESCE(@IDList + ', ', '') + '''''' + PersonID + '''''' 
FROM tmpGroup

select '''SELECT SystemID
FROM People
WHERE PersonID IN (' + @IDList + ')''' AS GroupSQL
```

Note it uses VARCHAR(8000) because that's the only source data type that seems to work.

Comment: I tend to use stored procedures for this, so my Execute SQL Tasks typically just have to pass parameters to the stored proc.

Comment: I haven't tried these ideas specifically to get around length issue but have used similar techniques for other things...anyway, you could try a Data Flow to select from your DB then place in a ODBC Recordset variable (object) if you need to recurse later in foreach loop or something.  Or you go from source to a script component and set a string variable with the value.  I am not sure if you will or will not run into the 8000 character limit that is on the data flow source component text input box if you turn around and use the variable later or not. Or script task to variable right away...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed similar problem with the following:

1. In Execute SQL Task - set **ResultSet = Full result set** and assign Object variable (VObj) as a result set.
2. After this task - create Foreach ADO enumerator and process Vobj as the source variable ([see good walk through article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14341/Using-the-Foreach-ADO-Enumerator-in-SSIS)), assigning the first variable to some String variable.

Described approach allowed to transfer long (more that 8K symbols) strings from SQL into SSIS String variable.

Comment: That works, thanks!  Matt's method of putting the query in a stored procedure works great, as well---I actually already had a stored procedure for other tasks so I ended up including that piece of code.